# How could create a composite index with property of embedded object

Tags: indexing, orientdb

I am trying to create a composite index with property of embedded object

This is what I have tried and I get the following error.

```
create class TestClass
create class SharedClass
create property SharedClass.UniqueProp string
create property TestClass.StringProp string
create property TestClass.LinkProp Link TestClass
create property TestClass.EmbeddedProp Embedded SharedClass

create index ix_unique1 on TestClass(StringProp, LinkProp) unique  ==> SUCCESS
create index ix_unique2 on TestClass(StringProp, EmbeddedProp.UniqueProp) unique  ==> FAILED
```

ERROR:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Index with name : 'ix_unique2' cannot be created on class : 'TestClass' because field: 'EmbededProp.UniqueProp' is absent in class definition.

Comment: Indexes are created for properties of class, not for embedded ones.

Comment: So that would be a performance problem because some queries may need to filter and/or sort based on them.